# Problem with links when converting to comment

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-abilities, convert-to-comment

When a mod converts a post to a comment, if the post contains a link of this form:

```
Check out this [awesome site][1]

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/
```

the comment will try to use the same syntax, but fail since that doesn't work in comments. Can it automatically convert to this syntax instead?

```
Check out this [awesome site](http://stackoverflow.com/)
```

Comment: If you think about it, the logical answer to any Stack Overflow question is to link them to Stack Overflow. It's where they'll find the answer they need, after all.

Comment: @Grace I'm going to spam "Belongs on SO" comments on every SO question I can find

Comment: Just FYI, Tim Post also requested at ♦ Moderator dashboard too - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72202/moderator-dashboard-help-us-help-you-help-us-all/84548#84548

Comment: FYI This is happening again, at least on money.stackexchange.com.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90161/bug-moderator-convert-to-comment-doesnt-handle-default-link-format

Comment: @Jeff There's a comment and an answer about how this isn't fixed (I haven't run into it again)

Comment: @Jeff - This is _not_ fixed. At least not for automatically converted answers. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112742/certain-links-get-broken-when-automatically-converting-trivial-answers-into-comm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, we now do a best effort to convert footnote style links to inline links prior to changing posts into comments.

Be advised that converting a post with complex formatting to a comment is .. not really a good idea, in the big scheme of things.

Answer (score 1):

This is *not fixed*.

[image]

> Be advised that converting a post with complex formatting to a comment is .. not really a good idea, in the big scheme of things.

Then *stop doing it*.

Answer (score 1):

It is still not fixed (at least in 2017).

The answer [Possible to default DateTime field to GETDATE() with Entity Framework Migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594431/possible-to-default-datetime-field-to-getdate-with-entity-framework-migrations/9875597#9875597) ( visible for 10k+ reputation users)

> “just had a similar probably, and found a good solution. Hope this
> helps: [EF 4.3.1 Migration Exception - AlterColumn defaultValueSql
> creates same default constraint name for different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830216/ef-4-3-1-migration-exception-altercolumn-defaultvaluesql-creates-same-default/)”  edited May
> 23, 2017 at 11:47

was converted to a comment

> just had a similar probably, and found a good solution. Hope this
> helps: [stackoverflow.com/questions/9830216/…](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830216/ef-4-3-1-migration-exception-altercolumn-defaultvaluesql-creates-same-default/)  – Thiago Silva Mar 26,
> 2012 at 16:03

The fully described title of the link became user-unfriendly truncated link.

Can it be ensured that the full names are not changed to a URL during conversion?

If a URL is shown, it should  not be truncated, because end of the link is often more meaningful for a reader.

In a comment @Laurel pointed, that particular issue is related to another long-waiting change request [Replace links with the current question title in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments)

Comment: This is not the same problem mentioned in the question and probably not a bug at all. Was the link in the answer formatted in markdown at all or was it auto-converted to a title link? That's something that only happens in posts.

Comment: @Laurel Exactly, it's a link that was auto-converted to a title. Both the answer and comment have the exact same markdown; it's just displayed differently.

Comment: @Laurel I  didn’t say is it a bug, it is undesirable behavior from the user/ SO content point of view. I agree that potential fix will be to resolve links to name in comments the same way as for posts (better for all comments, but at least for converted from answers). Do you think that it’s better to raise as a separate feature request?