# Link not handled well when answer was converted to a comment

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown, convert-to-comment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with links when converting to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74998/problem-with-links-when-converting-to-comment)

I just converted an answer to a comment on [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/60065/226). The answer contained a link and the comment appeared as follows:

[image: Defect screenshot]

Comment: Would not say it is a bug.. Just not implemented. Comments only allow `[]( )` types no?

Comment: @Philippe Yeah, but when a mod converts an answer to a comment, I think it's a case that should be handled better.

Comment: Too bad you can't edit the comment like you can an answer.

Comment: @jmort253 Sarcasm?

Comment: @Anna - Lol, no.  I'm kind of a neat freak and hate seeing blatant typos ;)  It could be a nice feature to have.  Or we could just learn to deal with the minor things like that and stop being so OCD :)

Comment: @jmort253 Moderators can edit comments, so it's not a huge deal. :)

Comment: @Anna - Did you see my answer below?  I guess I'd been doing it the hard way all this time :)  lol, duh!  I guess my method is only creative if you're a little slow :)  Now I get the sarcasm comment :)  I forgot moderators can see `edit` on everyone's comments.

Answer (score 2):

You need to break out your "Moderator edits comment" card and play that on the table.

Not everything is going to convert well when dropping from answer block to comment line.

Comment: I just report 'em as I see 'em. :)