# Convert to Comment Moderator ability doesn't handle default link format

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-abilities, convert-to-comment

If an answer uses a link with the default format (using `[link text][1]`) and later `[1]: http://somelink.com/` then when a moderator does convert-to-comment it doesn't become a link.

It should convert to `[link text](http://somelink.com/)` without the moderator having to go edit the comment.

Here is the answer text to [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/8215/why-do-non-electronic-stock-exchanges-still-exist) that was converted to a comment:

> Hopefully someone else (who knows more
>   about it than I do) will post an
>   answer that describes how trading
>   actually works these days and why the
>   physical stock exchange is necessary.
>   However, the 2010 "[flash crash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_Flash_Crash)"
>   is a good reminder of what happens
>   when we let computers take over.

Comment: This was [supposed to have been fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74998/problem-with-links-when-converting-to-comment), @YOU was right. Looks like it's resurged, or summat?

Comment: This is an answer with [a link](http://example.com) in it that I will convert to a comment. If this worked, then it works.

Comment: @Jeff: I know this happened to me yesterday on SO; was it fixed very recently?

Comment: @mmy it's probably bad formatting in the post. We also only convert that exact (default) link style. It's a best effort thing, there are no guarantees since there are about 5 different ways to make a link.

Comment: @Jeff: See [the 10th comment (the one by offengehirn) on this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24201/how-did-the-slang-meaning-of-flog-come-about) on ELU, converted just a minute ago. For all I can tell, it *is* that exact default link style. (Check the deleted answer's source.) Thanks.

Comment: Some words need to be appreciated for their versatility. [This site][1] demonstrates the query quite explicitly. [1]: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=flog

Comment: @reg ok that's a repro then.. I'll look. It's probably something really subtle / simple.

Comment: @Jeff: [another repro](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3411/why-did-hyperspace-kill-the-men-in-the-book-i-robot#comment-5393)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I see the issue -- for some reason I wasn't allowing leading spaces in the footnote style links.

e.g.

```
[1]: http://example.com
```

would work but

```
  [1]: http://example.com
```

would not