# Can 'convert to comment' be tweaked to deal with HTML links

Tags: bug, status-declined, hyperlinks, moderator-tools, convert-to-comment

Currently when converting an answer to a comment that contains links as `<a href="">` rather than in markdown this breaks the conversion:

[image: Demonstration of conversion problem]

I know this is likely to be quite uncommon and can be manually fixed but it would still save some time if the conversion could be done fully in the first instance?

---

*Similar questions but using markdown rather than HTML*

- [Convert to Comment Moderator ability doesn't handle default link format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90161/176080) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [Certain links get broken when automatically converting trivial answers into comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112742/certain-links-get-broken-when-automatically-converting-trivial-answers-into-comm)

Comment: `<comment>` I think it would be better to teach folks the proper use of markdown.  I've been here awhile, and it's very rare that I have the need to use HTML tags anywhere. `</comment>`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this issue up. At this time I have to side with Robert Harvey and agree that users should be using Markdown as opposed to HTML. Comments do not and will not support HTML, so in the rare case that an answer with HTML is converted to a comment, the comment will remain broken until further edits are made.

Comment: Why allow HTML in posts then?