# Certain links get broken when automatically converting trivial answers into comments

Tags: bug, status-declined, convert-to-comment, trivial

When a trivial answer contains links in the form:

```
[link][1] info info

[1]:http://example.com
```

When they are converted to a comment, the links get mangled to something like:

```
[link][2] info info [1]:http://example.com
```

Can we please have better logic in the conversion?

Alternatively, if the answer contains a link, do not consider it to be trivial.

**Update**:

Just to clarify that what I would like to see is that answers with that get converted, get converted properly.

If the answer was using the following link style:

```
[link][3] info info 

 [1]:http://example.com
```

It should get converted to:

```
[link](http://example.com) info info
```

Instead of:

```
[link][4] info info [1]:http://example.com
```

---

Update:

This is still happening. Just seen [in the wild](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8510525/1583):

[image]

Comment: here is a proper [example][1].


  [1]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112742/140505

Comment: The comment above ^^^^ was automatically converted from an answer with a link.

Comment: If the answer is **just** a link then it is trivial. The link should only be used to back up the answer.

Comment: Does the automatic conversion work only for users with a reputation lower than a value? I tried in the sandbox here on meta, and the answer was not converted in a comment.

Comment: @ChrisF - And if it is a few words and a link? I tend to do that and then expand.

Comment: Obviously there are borderline cases which would need determining, but posting link + a few words to get the first answer in isn't a reason to allow the behaviour.

Comment: @Arjan - Looks like you sparked off this question being closed... help!

Comment: (Hmmm, was this the question to which I commented I did not support my own close vote? That comment is gone now then, but I see things have been re-opened, so no sweat I hope.)

Comment: @Arjan - Yes, this is the same question, I flagged it to the moderators after it was closed, so it looks like they re-opened it.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate?

Comment: @Fezziwig - There was a similar question about the moderators tool (which supposedly was fixed). This is not about that tool but about the _automatic_ conversion.

Comment: Ah. I would really hope they use the same code, but maybe not

Comment: @Fezziwig - Well... they might be and the moderation tool regressed...

Comment: This is still happening, see my comment [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#autocomment542442), should the `status-completed` tag be removed or should I ask a new question?

Comment: Why is this by design? If the syntax won't be fixed during conversion then why bother converting it?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - Possibly should have tagged it as [meta-tag:status-declined] instead.

Comment: @Oded Declined? Ok, I'll just share my thoughts for what it's worth - Only short answers with links gets converted to comments, right? There are 2 types of links: `[]()` and `[][1] [1]:`, the second being the one used when you click "Hyperlink" (thus, probably the most popular one). Seems like a pretty mayor flaw to have functionality where the way it's most used doesn't display properly. [Most of these](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/112899) are probably the applicable comments.

Comment: @Dukeling - As the person who actually asked this (prior to becoming hired by SE), I can understand why this is not something worth spending time on (if an answer is so bad it is converted to a comment, perhaps that comments is also bad). And since one gets notified of auto converts, you have an immediate chance to fix it yourself.

Comment: @Oded Fair point. Let me finish by saying, in terms of not spending a lot of time on it, seems like a (probably overly-specific) regex-replace might be a start to at least cover most of them (with 1 link) - Replace `\[([^\]]*)\]\[1\](.*)\[1\]: (http://[^ ]*)$` with `[$1]($3)$2`. Worth a consideration. [Java test](https://ideone.com/eoJYYV).

Comment: +1 because this is still a rough spot in the SE experience. Trivial answers should be easy to convert; answers that are hard to convert probably aren't trivial.